# Output value from Json Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm getting output: `[{"ref":"contact.html","score":0.7071067811865475}]`

```
 $.getJSON( "index.json", function(content) {  
        idx = lunr.Index.load(content);
        var results = idx.search(variabletosearch);
        var final = JSON.stringify(results);
        console.log(final);
});
```

How can I print value of ref? When I `console.log(final[0].ref);` I get undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `final` is a string (the output of `JSON.stringify`)... you probably want to `console.log(results[0].ref);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

JSON.stringify returns a string, not an object. So in this case 'final' is a string that contains the same data that was in the object 'results'

To access the data from an object, you can use result[0].ref, or if you want to use 'final' (although you don't need to), you can do this:

```
final = JSON.parse(final)
console.log(final[0].ref)
```

---

If it's only one object within the array, then the other answers are enough, but since arrays are used to store multiple objects, you can do this as follows:

```
var arr = [
    {"ref": "object1", "score": "1"},
    {"ref": "object2", "score": "2"}
]

arr.map(function(object) {
    console.log(object.ref)
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znL87ojj/) using an alert instead of console.log()

You can also use a loop, but this cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [{"ref":"contact.html","score":0.7071067811865475}];

a[0].ref;
```

`a[0]` is the '0'th (or first) element in the array which is the object literal `{"ref":"contact.html","score":0.7071067811865475}` from here you can access the object normally using dot notation.

Expanded out a bit:

```
var a = [{"ref":"contact.html","score":0.7071067811865475}];
var myObject = a[0];
console.log(myObject.ref);
//or with null checking
if (myObject) {
  console.log(myObject.ref ? myObject.ref : 'no value');
}
```

Comment: I don't have the variable ready, actually I get it through lunr(lunrjs.com)
   $.getJSON( "index.json", function(content) {  
       searchterm = "randomstring";
        idx = lunr.Index.load(content);
        var results = idx.search(searchterm);
        var final = JSON.stringify(results);
        console.log(final[0].ref);
});   
But I get undefined. But when I console.log(final), i get [{"ref":"contact.html","score":0.7071067811865475}]

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming

```
var myvar = [{"ref":"contact.html","score":0.7071067811865475}];
```

then:

```
var myref = myvar[0].ref;
```